# Using awk to make changes to nth character in nth line in a file

Tags: linux, awk

I have written an awk command

`awk 'NR==5 {sub(substr($1,14,1),(substr($1,14,1) + 1)); print  "test.py"}' >  test.py`

This is trying to change the 14th character on the 5th line of a python file. For some reason this doesn't stop executing and I have to break it. It also deletes the contents of the file.

Sample input:

```
import tools

tools.setup(
    name='test',
    tagvisc='0.0.8',
    packages=tools.ges(),
    line xyz
)
```

`

Output:

```
import tools

tools.setup(
    name='test',
    tagvisc='0.0.9',
    packages=tools.ges(),
    line xyz
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Provide sample input with expected output.

Comment: @anubhava added it

Comment: So you want to increment the 14th character in the 5th record by `1`? If the character is a digit `+1` will be treated as a numeric addition. (e.g. `9` becomes `10`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes precisely!

Comment: Why not remove `"test.py"` and leave `print; exit` and run it as `awk '{...}' test.py > tmp; mv -f tmp test.py`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it deletes the contents of the file. Ran it as `awk 'NR==5 {sub(substr($1,14,1),(substr($1,14,1) + 1)); exit}'  test.py > tmp; mv -f tmp test.py`

Comment: Yes, I thought you said you only wanted to save the new line as the file? If not, remove the exit. and `"test.py"` and do it as `awk '{...}1' test.py > tmp; mv -f tmp test.py` Too bad you can't increment pattern space in `sed`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can do it in sed but I don't know how to

Comment: if the input is `tagvisc="3.4.10",` then this will generate `tagvisc="3.4.20"` (and not `tagvisc="3.4.11"`); is that what you want? I'm guessing you really want to increment, what is that, a version number? if this is the case you'll want to do away with the hardcoded character position and instead look at this from the view of modifying a field in the line

Comment: @markp-fuso ah! you're right! how can you do that? because this whole thing is one field.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what you suggested worked but as mark mentioned this won't work when the number is a double digit.

Comment: You are off-by-one, `awk 'NR == 5 {sub(substr($1,13,1),(substr($1,13,1) + 1))}1' test.py > tmp; mv -f tmp test.py` Character 14 was the `','` at the end of the field. Example: `echo tagvisc="3.4.6", | awk '{sub(substr($1,13,1),(substr($1,13,1) + 1))}1'` Result `tagvisc=3.4.7,` Yes, for double digits, (multiple) you will have to adjust the regex)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 14 works fine. But when the digit goes to 10, the code will make it 20 instead of 11.

Comment: there is also a hidden problem with the `sub`, assume you have the value `3.4.3`. This will increment the first occurrence of 3.

Comment: You will need to use `split()` to split that field into an array and then increment and put it back together. See [GNU Awk User's Guide - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

Comment: I'd go with Perl, here, `perl -i -pe 's/^\h*tagvisc='"'"'\d+\.\d+\.\K\d+/($&+1)/e' test.py`, or, if the line is important, `perl -i -pe 's/^\h*tagvisc='"'"'\d+\.\d+\.\K\d+/($&+1)/e if $. == 5' test.py`

Comment: Or simpler, `perl -i -pe 's/(.*\.)(\d+)/$1.($2+1)/e  if $. == 5' test.py`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in the first one you mentioned, why have you provided the tagvisc and $. == 5? 

Can you please explain the code. Can I remove $.==5

Comment: That means Line #5. If you do not care about line number, remove `if $. == 5`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But removing that works too. Oh I see you've mentioned `if the line is important`. My bad. Thanks perl seems better than awk. Would you say so?

Comment: It is much clearer and more maintainable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get away from the fixed line number (`NR==5`) and fixed character position (`14`) and  instead look at dynamically finding what you want to change/increment, eg:

```
$ cat test.py
import tools

tools.setup(
    name='test',
    tagvisc='0.0.10',
    packages=tools.ges(),
    line xyz
)
```

One `awk` idea to increment the `10` (3rd line, 3rd numeric string in line):

```
awk '
/tagvisc=/ { split($0,arr,".")                             # split line on periods
             sub("." arr[3]+0 "\047","." arr[3]+1 "\047")  # replace .<oldvalue>\047 with .<newvalue>\047; \047 == single quote
           }
1
' test.py
```

**NOTES:**

- `arr[3]` = `10',`; with `arr[3]+0` `awk` will take the leftmost all-numeric content, strip off everything else, then add `0`, leaving us with `arr[3]` = `10`; same logic applies for `arr[3]+1` (`arr[3]+1` = `11`); basically a trick for discarding any suffix that is not numeric
- if there are multiple lines in the file with the string `tagvisc='x.y.z'` then this will change `z` in all of the lines; we can get around this by adding some more logic to only change the `first` occurrence, but I'll leave that out for now assuming it's not an issue

This generates:

```
import tools

tools.setup(
    name='test',
    tagvisc='0.0.11',
    packages=tools.ges(),
    line xyz
)
```

If the objective is to overwrite the original file with the new values you have a couple options:

```
# use temporary file:

awk '...' test.py > tmp ; mv tmp test.py

# if using GNU awk, and once accuracy of script has been verified:

awk -i inplace '...' test.py
```

Comment: I am debugging, but this is making no changes to my file.

Comment: are you using a temp file or `awk -i inplace`?

Comment: Yes, using tmp file

Comment: please update the question with the first 7 lines of your file

Comment: made the change

Comment: I see them ... that's not what was posted in the original question; let me review my code in light of the new info ...

Comment: yes, my apologies. Pretty new to this so didn't know what should be provided

Comment: answer updated; best bet is to provide an example of actual file otherwise we go round-n-round in circles when our suggestions are based on incorrect data

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the nuances of what you need to do now, you will need to split the first field of the 5th record into an array using `"."` as the fieldsep and then remove the `"\","` from the end of the 3rd element of the array (optional) before incrementing the number and putting the field back together. You can do so with:

```
awk '{split($1,a,"."); sub(/["],/,"",a[3]); $1=a[1]"."a[2]"."(a[3]+1)"\","}1'
```

(`NR==5` omitted for example)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo 'tagvisc="3.4.30"', | 
  awk '{split($1,a,"."); sub(/["],/,"",a[3]); $1=a[1]"."a[2]"."(a[3]+1)"\","}1'
tagvisc="3.4.31",
```

I'll leave redirecting to a temp file and then back to the original to you. Let me know if this isn't what you need.

Adding `NR == 5` you would have

```
awk 'NR==5 {split($1,a,"."); sub(/["],/,"",a[3]); $1=a[1]"."a[2]"."(a[3]+1)"\","}1' test.py > tmp; mv -f tmp test.py
```

Comment: it adds `..1` to every line. I guess we will have to put a line number

Comment: You need to add the `NR==5` condition -- I left it out for the example. Also note I fixed a typo of `","` to `"."` between `a[2]` and `a[3]`

Comment: Actually you can use `'{split($1,a,"."); $1=a[1]"."a[2]"."(a[3]+1)"\","}1'` as `awk` will discard trailing non-digits on conversion to a numeric value when adding `+1`.

Comment: Okay, so this works but the file has some blank spaces in front of the line, this makes them dissapear.

Comment: Yes, there are a few ways to handle that, none trivial. The reason is that you are using the default `FS` which splits fields on whitespace. Multiple whitespace is treated as a single delimiter. You can save the number of leading spaces in `$0` and append them back if that is required.

Comment: Note, if all lines don't start with `tagvisc=`, then add that as your condition. As karakfa and mark have done. Then you don't need to count records and the only record modified will be the one beginning `tagvisc=`,

Comment: Okay, working through the blank spaces now

Comment: Give this a go `echo '    tagvisc="3.4.30"', |  awk '{match($0,/^[[:blank:]]*/,spaces); split($1,a,"."); sub(/["],/,"",a[3]); $1=spaces[0] a[1]"."a[2]"."(a[3]+1)"\","}1'` You will need to add the other conditions. This just shows how to use `match()` to capture the leading whitespace in the array `spaces` and reinsert the matched portion `spaces[0]` in the output. You can also do `awk '{match($0,/^[[:blank:]]*/); split($1,a,"."); spaces=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/["],/,"",a[3]); $1=spaces a[1]"."a[2]"."(a[3]+1)"\","}1'`

Answer (score 2):

*Using awk to make changes to nth character in* [mth] *line in a file*:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}NR==5{$18=9}1' file # > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Outputs:

```
import tools

tools.setup(
    name='test',
    tagvisc='0.0.9',   <----- this is not output but points to what changed
    packages=tools.ges(),
    line xyz
)
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=""    # set the field separators to empty and you can reference
}                # each char in record by a number
NR==5 {          # 5th record
    $18=9        # and 18th char is replaced with a 9
}1' file         # > tmp && mv tmp file # output to a tmp file and replace
```

**Notice:** Some awks (probably all but GNU awk) will fail if you try to replace a multibyte char by a single byte one (for example utf8 `ä` (0xc3 0xa4) with an `a` (0x61) will result in 0x61 0xa4). Naturally an `ä` before the position you'd like to replace will set your calculations off by 1.

Oh yeah, you can replace one char with multiple chars but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
$ awk 'function join(a,k,s,sep) {for(k in a) {s=s sep a[k]; sep="."}  return s}
       BEGIN {FS=OFS="\""}
       /^tagvisc=/{v[split($2,v,".")]++; $2=join(v)}1' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and "inplace" editing:

```
$ awk -i inplace '
    match($0,/^([[:space:]]*tagvisc=\047)([^\047]+)(.*)/,a) {
        split(a[2],ver,".")
        $0 = a[1] ver[1] "." ver[2] "." ver[3]+1 a[3]
    }
    { print }
' test.py
```

```
$ cat test.py
import tools

tools.setup(
    name='test',
    tagvisc='0.0.9',
    packages=tools.ges(),
    line xyz
)
```